# Elasticsearch Unassigned Shard: How to reassign back?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have 3 data node cluster and all our indices have 1 primary + 2 replica shards on each index. All the indices were running properly with a green status for the cluster until a couple of days ago.

For some reason, only one of the indices now has a yellow status with 1 unassigned index error. When I run `_cluster/allocation/explain`, it tells me that "the shard cannot be allocated to the same node on which a copy of the shard already exists". If I look at the cluster health on Kibana, I don't see a duplicate shard on that node.

[image]

So I am not quite sure what the problem is. Can someone offer any advice on this?

Answer (score 2):

This statement is correct.

`the shard cannot be allocated to the same node on which a copy of the shard already exists` as it doesn't make sense to assign the replicas(R) on the same node where primary shard(P) of a index is present, a**s replicas are used to provide the high-availability and fault-tolerance and always assigned to the node where replica's primary shard is not present.**

Now in your case, you mentioned you have 3 data node and all your indices also have 3 shards(1 P+ 2R) which makes it ideal to assign 1 shard(be it P or R shard) on each data nodes.

Also you are correct that `cluster health on Kibana, I don't see a duplicate shard on that node.` and it can't happen that P or R can be on same node.

As you have already used the `_cluster/allocation/explain` I am assuming that you already know the problematic index, so just follow the advise mentioned in this [discuss post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-fix-cluster-health-yellow-with-elastic-search/23484), **In short, reduce the no of replica for problematic index to just 1 or increase data node.**

Comment: Thanks for your response but I think my current setup should work (at least it is working for other indices except this one). I have 3 nodes and when I defined my index I specified `number_of_shards:3` and `number_of_replicas:2`. So I have totally 9 shards distributed on 3 nodes which works for all the indices except the one above (look at my screenshot). I have replica #2 unassigned. It should be able to exist on Node 2 because that shard does not exist. So why am I getting an error? Why should I reduce replica or increase node? Do you see a problem with the way I have defined my parameters?

Comment: @hvs sorry for the dealy in response and thanks for detailed info and yes you are absolutely correct and in ideal situation it shouldn't happen and that's the reason you are not seeing it on other indices, maybe there was some issue while creating this index which caused some issues in shard allocation or some other issues which is now very difficult to debug without logs. what I suggested is to now overcome this issue and believe me it happened with us so many times in production and as we were not loosing any data, thanks to replica we didn't bother to debug the issue, rather than fixed it.

Comment: @hvs also when you deal with distributing systems these issues are expected but again it depends on your use-case wheather you want to focus on complete RCA of such difficult and known issues or focus on fix, in my case we didn't have the time and went ahead with the solution as we were not loosing any data. Hope this clarifies :)

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the index and open again. It force to redistribute shards, al least on my cluster.